# Is it possible to access contents of anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, function

It's a very brief question. Is it possible for me to access variables, objects, functions that are inside an anonymous function?

I need to access an object that contains functions. I need only one function, call it again. But this code is inside an anonymous function. I can't run from there, because the reason is not to have conflicts with the various js that are on the page.

And there?

Comment: No, symbols declared inside a function are stuck there. Of course the function can return values computed internally, but you cannot "reach inside" a function.

Comment: The only way to get variables out of a function is to `return` them or make them use global variables when writing them.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*I can't run from there, because the reason is not to have conflicts with the various js*". What code would be supposed to call the function that you want to call?

Answer (score 1):

Before modules became common in JavaScript it was not uncommon to do what you're asking by assigning the output of an anonymous function to a global variable. One single global variable that has methods and properties made available through it is considered a good practice. There's still the chance for conflicts, but a lot less with a single global variable.

```
const myAnonFunction = (() => {
  function a() {
    // ...
  }
  function b() {
    a();
    // ...
  }
  function c() {
    // ...
  }


  return {
   b,
   c,
  }
})();
```

In the above code we create an anonymous function and immediately execute it, note the `()` on the last line. The output of the function is assigned to the global constant `myAnonFunction`. You can then access anything that is in the return statement externally such as `myAnonFunction.b()` and `myAnonFunction.c()`, but you will be unable to access `.a()` because it is not returned.